# Inequation of an sum smaller than 1

Tags: inequality, summation, exponential-sum

I'm trying to figure out the following
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{n=3} \dfrac{q!^2}{n!^2} < 1
$$
How I can show it if $q \geq 2$?

Maybe with telescoping sums?

Thanks,

Landau

Comment: Duh!! is something missing in question?

Comment: no, you're right! i mean n=3 :) sorry ill try to change!

Comment: but not the n´th power.

Comment: probably you mean, $q^2 \le 3$, if you put $q=3$ you get $3!^2/3!^2 = 1$ as your first term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac1{(n!)^2} = I_0(2)$$
where $I_0(z)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind. In your problem,
$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \dfrac1{(n!)^2} = I_0(2) - \dfrac94 \approx 0.029585302336067267$$
Hence, we get $$(q!)^2 < 34 \implies q! < 6 \implies q < 3$$

Answer (score 1):

Provided that $q\leq 3$, each term of the sum is less than or equal to $1$
and is therefore less than or equal to its square root. Using the power series expansion for $e$, we find that
$$
\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{q!^2}{n!^2} < \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{q!}{n!}
= q!\Big(e-\frac{5}{2}\Big),
$$
and this expression is less than $1$ when $q\leq 2$